# Linq to NHibernate - select count problem

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Given the classes A and B where

```
class A
{
 string Name;
 Ilist<B> BList;
}

class B
{
 string Name;
}
```

With FluentNH mapping, relationship is many-to-many which is HasManyToMany(x => x.B) for A. B has no reference to A. NH version is 2.1.2.4000.

**What should be the linq query to select the collection where each row contains B.Name and count of A's containing that B?** Result must be the List of anonymous type who has 2 fields: Name and Count. Result also should include all B's, hence it should be outer join.

My intend is to get the result with minimum round-trips to database, possibly in one go.

Comment: What collectction? Array of A, or Array of B, or IQueriable of something? Clearify your question, please)

Comment: Please include your mapping files? Are you using NH2.1.2 or NH3? Your first attempt at your LINQ query would also help clarify your intent.

Comment: @The_Smallest and @James I edited the question I hope it helps.

Comment: BTW: "A" and "B" is not the best way to call classes. "Category" and "SubCategory", "User" and "Group", is easier to understand))

Comment: A and B are only representations of 2 classes in applications domain. They are not real class names.

Comment: I understand that in your model it's called with normal names. Why didn't you give us normal names, domain-specific. It's easier to speak, when you say "All Users from Specific Groups", than "All a from specific Bs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in Linq in one hit in code, you could do this...

```
var result = Session.Linq<A>()
    .SelectMany(a => a.BList, (a, b) => new { b.Name, A = a.Id })
    .ToList()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

`NHibernate.Linq` (2.1.2.4000) can't handle a `GroupBy` after a `SelectMany` it seems, so the first `ToList` pulls all the data into memory. This is inefficient -- a SQL count would be better.

Alternatively, you could add a lazy loaded collection to your `B` class that goes back to `A`. If you're using a many-to-many table in the middle, that should be easy.

```
public class B
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<A> AList { get; private set; }
}
```

Your query simply becomes...

```
var result = Session.Linq<B>()
    .Where(b => b.AList.Count > 0)
    .Select(b => new { b.Name, b.AList.Count }
    .ToList();
```

Which produces very efficient SQL from Linq (using a count) and gives the same result.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the requirement is outer join, all B's from table B. (I edited the  question as it still seemed not crystal-clear). but i guess from your last query removing where clause will do that. i'll try that way.